# R: Create matrix of values from other table

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, dataframe, transfer

I have the following data frame, `table5`, made up of `x` and its frequency, produced from other data using `counts`:

```
  x freq
1 1    3
2 3   21
3 4   21
4 5 1345
5 7    1
```

which I would like to transfer - in a general fashion, i.e. for use with other values in original data frame - into the following data frame `table5if`:

```
      Frequency
3             21
4             21
5             1345
other         4
```

i.e. where the frequency of the numbers 3, 4 and 5 is transferred directly, and all other numbers are added together in `other`. My latest attempt is this:

```
k <- seq(1, nrow(table5), by=1)
    ifelse(table5$x[k] == 3, table5if[1] <- table5$freq[k],
          ifelse(table5$x[k] == 4, table5if[2] <- table5$freq[k],
                ifelse(table5$x[k] == 5, table5if[3] <- table5$freq[k], table5if[4] <- (table5if[4] + table5$freq[k])
                  )
            )
      )
```

This attempt, and other attempts using `if(...){...} else {...} etc.`, have all yielded some form of warning or error (e.g. "number of items to replace..." and "number of dimensions..." and haven't produced any convincing results. I've looked through countless other questions for both errors/warnings and can't quite find what I'm looking for - there's a lot about vectorisation but I can't quite get my head around why that would be the issue. Can anyone please suggest a suitable option for this small task?

Comment: Why not just add all the frequencies and then subtract those for numbers 3, 4 and 5 to compute the total for others?

Comment: This certainly would be the simplest option! I'm also a fan of avoiding ready made functions and keeping it down to maths and logic. Many thanks for your suggestion, windrunn3r.1990!

Answer (score 3):

I would aggregate by `factor(x, levels = 3:5)` while all the non-present levels will become `NA`. You can then change this afterwards to `"other"` if you like. `data.table` is convenient in this case as it keeps the `NA`s a separate group instead of omitting them

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Frequency = sum(freq)), by = factor(x, levels = 3:5)]
#    factor Frequency
# 1:     NA         4
# 2:      3        21
# 3:      4        21
# 4:      5      1345
```

Comment: This also worked superbly! Many thanks, David Arenburg.

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option would be to create a logical index based on the values of 'x' column with `%in%`. We get the `sum` of 'freq' based on the negated index of 'i1' and `rbind` with the subset rows of 'table5'.

```
i1 <- table5$x %in% 3:5
`row.names<-`(rbind(table5[i1,], list(x= "Other", 
          freq=sum(table5[!i1,"freq"]))), NULL)
#      x freq
#1     3   21
#2     4   21
#3     5 1345
#4 Other    4
```

Comment: This worked an absolute treat! I've tested it with manipulated values from table5 and had no problems. +10 street creds for you, akrun! Thank you very much.